# Laravel eloquent relationship has many joints

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables that I want to join

```
table users             table comments                      table posts
| id | name |     | id | user_id | post_id | comment |    | id| text |   
|----|------|     | -- | ------- | ------- | ------- |    |---| ---- |
| 1  | a    |     | 1  |    1    |    2    |    b    |    | 1 |   a  |
| 2  | b    |     | 2  |    1    |    1    |    c    |    | 2 |   b  |
```

i want to display it like this

```
| id | user_id | name | post_id | comment |
```

i only know joining tables between comments and posts using hasMany relationship

how to join more table (in this case users table) with eloquent relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You can join using following code. But I dont think you can display the record as `| id | user_id | name | post_id | comment |` because you will have - a user can have many comments and a comment can have many posts. So you will not be able to show on same row. But you can make use of arrays.

An example

```
$user=User::with(['comments','comments.post'])->get();
```